# Cannot install anything via PIP to virtual environment

Tags: python

When starting a new virtual environment, I am finding it impossible to install any packages via pip. For example, if I try to install mock within a brand new virtualenv, I get the following error:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission     
denied: '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock.pyc'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

If I try to install with the --user option, I get this error:

```
Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in
this virtualenv.
```

In accordance with [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50639973/pip-problems-could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror), I tried changing the ownership of the folder containing my virtual environment but no luck. I know using sudo for pip will mess up the install. This hasn't happened before, and I am utterly stuck. Please help.

Comment: Try this :- https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/issues/236#issuecomment-383039470

Comment: What command dis you use to change the ownership?

Comment: Is your `virtualenv` activated? Also, try adding user ownership to `/usr/lib/python2.7`

Comment: @ahmad-rahimi, to change the ownership of the virtualenv, I am using sudo chown <<my username>>: /path/to/venv

Comment: @Arihant, Virtualenv is activated. I changed the ownership of `/usr/lib/python2.7` as suggested. I then attempted to install a pip package, which seemed to work, but when I called `pip freeze` , no packages showed up.

Comment: Is `pip list` working?

Comment: @Arihant, `pip list` works, but only lists pip, setuptools, and wheel, nothing that I have tried to install manually

Comment: Sorry to ask again, did you `pip install` after activating the `venv`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it appears the problem was my virtualenvironment kept wanting to install pip packages to the global directory and not its own.

What fixed it was deleting the old virtualenv and initializing a new one with the command:
    `virtualenv <<name of env>> --python=python2.7`

I'm not entirely sure why this worked. I would love any clarification in the comments.