# Pip: permission denied when installing packages using --user flag

Tags: python, macos, pip

I am trying to install `jupyter`

`pip install --user jupyter`

However I get this error:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7'
Check the permissions.
```

How do I check the permissions of `--user`? How do I change the permission of `--user`?

Full log:

```
morgans-imac:~ morganallen$ pip install --user jupyter
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Collecting jupyter
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/83/df/0f5dd132200728a86190397e1ea87cd76244e42d39ec5e88efd25b2abd7e/jupyter-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting qtconsole (from jupyter)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e0/7a/8aefbc0ed078dec7951ac9a06dcd1869243ecd7bcbce26fa47bf5e469a8f/qtconsole-4.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting notebook (from jupyter)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f8/a6/dbdf0954d073ab2cf5421cad20334d1e4c780da37205c04522c045298f67/notebook-5.7.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting nbconvert (from jupyter)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b5/bb/94c493051d60e5b9c0f7f9a368b324201818c1b1c4cae85d1e49a41846c7/nbconvert-5.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ipywidgets (from jupyter)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/30/9a/a008c7b1183fac9e52066d80a379b3c64eab535bd9d86cdc29a0b766fd82/ipywidgets-7.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jupyter-console (from jupyter)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/77/82/6469cd7fccf7958cbe5dce2e623f1e3c5e27f1bb1ad36d90519bc2d5d370/jupyter_console-5.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from jupyter) (4.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from qtconsole->jupyter) (2.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython-genutils in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from qtconsole->jupyter) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client>=4.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from qtconsole->jupyter) (5.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-core in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from qtconsole->jupyter) (4.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from qtconsole->jupyter) (4.3.2)
Collecting prometheus-client (from notebook->jupyter)
Collecting terminado>=0.8.1 (from notebook->jupyter)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2e/20/a26211a24425923d46e1213b376a6ee60dc30bcdf1b0c345e2c3769deb1c/terminado-0.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting nbformat (from notebook->jupyter)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/da/27/9a654d2b6cc1eaa517d1c5a4405166c7f6d72f04f6e7eea41855fe808a46/nbformat-4.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=17 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from notebook->jupyter) (17.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from notebook->jupyter) (2.9.6)
Collecting Send2Trash (from notebook->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=4 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from notebook->jupyter) (5.0.2)
Collecting ipaddress; python_version == "2.7" (from notebook->jupyter)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fc/d0/7fc3a811e011d4b388be48a0e381db8d990042df54aa4ef4599a31d39853/ipaddress-1.0.22-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting entrypoints>=0.2.2 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ac/c6/44694103f8c221443ee6b0041f69e2740d89a25641e62fb4f2ee568f2f9c/entrypoints-0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting bleach (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/05/27e1466475e816d3001efb6e0a85a819be17411420494a1e602c36f8299d/bleach-3.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pandocfilters>=1.4.1 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
Collecting defusedxml (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/87/1c/17f3e3935a913dfe2a5ca85fa5ccbef366bfd82eb318b1f75dadbf0affca/defusedxml-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting testpath (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/be/a4/162f9ebb6489421fe46dcca2ae420369edfee4b563c668d93cb4605d12ba/testpath-0.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting mistune>=0.8.1 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/09/ec/4b43dae793655b7d8a25f76119624350b4d65eb663459eb9603d7f1f0345/mistune-0.8.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: ipython<6.0.0,>=4.0.0; python_version < "3.3" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipywidgets->jupyter) (5.8.0)
Collecting widgetsnbextension~=3.4.0 (from ipywidgets->jupyter)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/81/35789a3952afb48238289171728072d26d6e76649ddc8b3588657a2d78c1/widgetsnbextension-3.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from jupyter-console->jupyter) (1.0.15)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from jupyter-client>=4.1->qtconsole->jupyter) (2.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from traitlets->qtconsole->jupyter) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34; python_version == "2.7" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from traitlets->qtconsole->jupyter) (1.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from traitlets->qtconsole->jupyter) (4.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: ptyprocess; os_name != "nt" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from terminado>=0.8.1->notebook->jupyter) (0.6.0)
Collecting jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4 (from nbformat->notebook->jupyter)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/77/de/47e35a97b2b05c2fadbec67d44cfcdcd09b8086951b331d82de90d2912da/jsonschema-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from jinja2->notebook->jupyter) (1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: futures in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tornado>=4->notebook->jupyter) (3.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: singledispatch in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tornado>=4->notebook->jupyter) (3.4.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: backports_abc>=0.4 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tornado>=4->notebook->jupyter) (0.5)
Collecting configparser>=3.5; python_version == "2.7" (from entrypoints>=0.2.2->nbconvert->jupyter)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/b1/98e5e3094aac1c0efaeb208fb45f9b42eb1d5681b4c5dac77b05d0fec71a/configparser-3.7.1-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting webencodings (from bleach->nbconvert->jupyter)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/24/2a3e3df732393fed8b3ebf2ec078f05546de641fe1b667ee316ec1dcf3b7/webencodings-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: simplegeneric>0.8 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython<6.0.0,>=4.0.0; python_version < "3.3"->ipywidgets->jupyter) (0.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: backports.shutil-get-terminal-size; python_version == "2.7" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython<6.0.0,>=4.0.0; python_version < "3.3"->ipywidgets->jupyter) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pexpect; sys_platform != "win32" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython<6.0.0,>=4.0.0; python_version < "3.3"->ipywidgets->jupyter) (4.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython<6.0.0,>=4.0.0; python_version < "3.3"->ipywidgets->jupyter) (32.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython<6.0.0,>=4.0.0; python_version < "3.3"->ipywidgets->jupyter) (0.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: appnope; sys_platform == "darwin" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython<6.0.0,>=4.0.0; python_version < "3.3"->ipywidgets->jupyter) (0.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pathlib2; python_version == "2.7" or python_version == "3.3" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from ipython<6.0.0,>=4.0.0; python_version < "3.3"->ipywidgets->jupyter) (2.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: wcwidth in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter-console->jupyter) (0.1.7)
Collecting functools32; python_version == "2.7" (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4->nbformat->notebook->jupyter)
Requirement already satisfied: scandir; python_version < "3.5" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from pathlib2; python_version == "2.7" or python_version == "3.3"->ipython<6.0.0,>=4.0.0; python_version < "3.3"->ipywidgets->jupyter) (1.9.0)
Installing collected packages: qtconsole, prometheus-client, configparser, entrypoints, functools32, jsonschema, nbformat, webencodings, bleach, pandocfilters, defusedxml, testpath, mistune, nbconvert, terminado, Send2Trash, ipaddress, notebook, widgetsnbextension, ipywidgets, jupyter-console, jupyter
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/morganallen/Library/Python/2.7'
Check the permissions.
```

Comment: OSX by the sound of it.

Comment: correct I am running this on a Mac

Comment: paste the full output of the command including the command itself, the important details are missing

Comment: Are you within a virtual environment?

Comment: I am not, do I need to be?

Comment: You don't have to, but that would trivially solve this (and then you don't even need or want the `--user` flag).

Comment: ideally I'd like to just install it onto my machine so I can just run python commands in a terminal / text editor without having to worry about starting up a virtualenv

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pip problems - Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50639973/pip-problems-could-not-install-packages-due-to-an-environmenterror)

Comment: Long story short, you've played with `sudo pip install --user` and borked the local stuff. Run `sudo chown -R morganallen:staff $HOME/Library/Python` to fix the ownership.

Comment: oh yea, I've used Sudo in the past (that's what I was initially told to do)...i usually just ran sudo pip install package

Comment: that worked! thank you. holy shit I've been dealing with this for ages hah